# How to Fix CA2100: SQL security vulnerability In Legacy code when SQL query is coming to function from outside of it?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, security

While working on legacy code, I ran into Specific scenario and made a dummy example to show the issue to ask for any suggestions. I get following error:
`

```
Program.cs(37,1) : warning  : CA2100 : Microsoft.Security : The query string passed to 'OleDbCommand.CommandText.set(string)' in 'Program.Read(OleDbConnection, string)' could contain the following variables 'sqlQuery'. If any of these variables could come from user input, consider using a stored procedure or a parameterized SQL query instead of building the query with string concatenations.
```

My Code is:

```
    class Program
        {
        static void Main ()
            {
            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Newfolder\database1.mdb";

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                try
                    {
                    connection.Open();
                    string strsql = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
                    Read(connection,strsql);
                    }
                catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }

        static void Read (OleDbConnection connection,string sqlQuery)
            {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
                {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["PName"]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now **I cannot go with the solution to suppress warning**. There are several complicated situations from which i get these warnings, this is just a dummy simple example to show workflow.
So although the query being executed is safe, but since it comes outside of the function, it asks me to changed it to parametrized query.
As in Read() function, although my input paramter sqlQuery is not from user, but it will come from outside as an input parameter **and I cannot move sqlQuery code within the Read() function**, it will always come from outside based on which certain decisions are made.
So what can I do to make this redundant warning disapper?

My dummy Access databse snapshot is this:
[image]

I have tried going through [Microsoft official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2100) on it, but i was not able to come up with solution

Comment: What you can do is the obvious thing: suppress the warning (and it is a warning, not an error). The analyzer doesn't perform cross-function analysis to see if it might be the case that your parameter value can only be from a fixed, limited set of values that's always safe.

Comment: There are three types of commands : Text, TableDirect, StoredProcedure.  I think the error indicates you need to set the type to Text : command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;  Default should be Text so not sure why you are getting warning.  Your picture is showing a table.  If it is a table than use TableDirect and you do not need a CommandText.

Comment: I haven't seen this issue in years.  It seems to only happen with Jet/Ace with Microsoft Office (Excel, Access).  Because you are using Select * from Table1 you are asking for entire table so warning is suggesting you use TableDirect.  If you did use asterisks than you wouldn't get warning.